# Use netcdf4 with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, netcdf

I am Currently Working on my Bachelors Degree, where I am to do a Data-Analysis using Jupyter Notebook. Normally I only write "normal" Python and Java code.
For this I need to open .NC Files, and a quick Google search told me to use netcdf4. Within my Anaconda Manager this was not a problem, but I can't seem to get it to work within Jupyter.

[Here you can see what I tried.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwkzT.png) I can do "import sys" and "!{sys.executable} -m pip install netcdf4" (which i got from another Stackoverflow Thread), but "import netcdf4 as nc" doesnt work. (Error Code

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-6eba77c50763> in <module>
----> 1 import netcdf4 as nc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netcdf4'
```

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you start the Jupyter Notebook with your desired Anaconda evironment activated? Normally Jupyter uses the virtual environment for python that it was started in. Also maybe try running `conda install netcdf64`.

Answer (score 0):

The netcdf4 package is not installed in your current environment. You could do the following in your notebook:

```
! pip install netcdf4
```

or conda install, depending on how you want to intall the package.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out after hours of trial and error.

Of course its "!{sys.executable} -m pip install netcdf4" (netcdf all lowercase letters), but to install its "import netCDF4 as nc" (CDF capitalized).

Those are the days i'd rather have studied economics.